# get data from server in android

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi i write android program to get data from server and show it in list view
but when i run program its show me empty list view
please see my code and help me:

MainActiviy class

```
package com.example.delta.mysite2;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] id,name,content,commentcount;
String tid,tname,tcontent,tcomment;
private int page=1;
private int count;
private String res="";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new getpost().execute();

}

private void makearray(int c){
    id=new String[c];
    name=new String[c];
    content=new String[c];
    commentcount=new String[c];

    Arrays.fill(name,"");
}

public class getpost extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        try {
            String data=      URLEncoder.encode("page","utf8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(page+"","utf8");
            URL link=new     URL("http://deltaspot.ir/test_android_server/wp/app/get.php");
            URLConnection connect=link.openConnection();

            //send data
            connect.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr=new   OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            String line=null;

            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            res=sb.toString();

            for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
                if(res.charAt(y)=='☻'){
                    count=Integer.parseInt(res.substring(0,y));
                    res=res.substring(y+1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            makearray(count);

            int f=0,c=0;

            for(int i=0;i<res.length();i++){
                if(res.charAt(i)=='☻'){
                    String temp=res.substring(f,i);

                    if(c==0){
                        tid=temp;
                    }
                    if(c==1){
                        tname=temp;
                    }
                    if(c==2){
                        tcontent=temp;
                    }
                    if(c==3){
                        tcomment=temp;

                        for(int t=0;t<count;t++){
                            if(name[t].equals("")){
                                id[t]=tid;
                                name[t]=tname;
                                content[t]=tcontent;
                                commentcount[t]=tcomment;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        c=-1;
                    }
                    f=i+1;
                    c+=1;
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            res=e.toString();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {

        super.onPostExecute(o);
        setListAdapter(new IA());
    }
}


public class IA extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public IA() {
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_main);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent, false);

        TextView titr=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_titr);
        TextView matn=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_content);
        TextView extra=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_extra);
        ImageView img=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_main_image);

        titr.setText(name[position]);
        matn.setText(content[position]);
        extra.setText("comment"+commentcount[position]);

        return (row);
    }
}
```

}

and the layout code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/row_main_image" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/row_main_titr"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/row_main_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_main_titr"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/row_main_titr"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/row_main_titr"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/row_main_extra"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_main_image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my code please help me to fix my problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if your `res` variable (`res=sb.toString();`) is not empty or null? (If you cannot debug just put a `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`)

Comment: Can you show us more of your log ?

Comment: the res variable is empty

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue may be that the adpater(IA) has the getView method doing what I believe should be done by the bindView method. That is try changing getView to bindView.

Additionally I believe that the the inflater code:-

```
LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();
View row=in.inflate(R.layout.row_main, parent, false);
```

belongs in the newView method.

Here's an example of a working adapter. However, this is for a Cursor. I do believe they are quite similar though:-

```
public class Database_Inspector_AislesDB_Adapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public Database_Inspector_AislesDB_Adapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView textviewaisleid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adiae_aislesdb_id);
        TextView textviewaisleshopref = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adiae_aislesdb_shopref);
        TextView textviewaislesorder = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adiae_aislesdb_order);
        TextView textviewaislesaislename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adiae_aislesdb_aislename);

        textviewaisleid.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
        textviewaislesaislename.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
        textviewaislesorder.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ORDER_INDEX));
        textviewaisleshopref.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
    }
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursos, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_database_inspect_aislesdb_entry, parent, false);
    }
}
```

The getView in this case is alternating the background colour.

Comment: i change getview to bindview but its not fix

Comment: with this code i want to show me the data from this link:                  http://deltaspot.ir/test_android_server/wp/app/get.php                                but i cannot do this , can you give me a source to do this for me,                   thank you

Comment: I would suggest splitting the task up into two chunks. 1) get the data, build an array and print the array to check that the array is populated and 2) using an array manually populated with a few entries get the listview adapter etc working. When you are happy with both then merge them together.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the adapter that x no of row would be there.

replace this

```
    super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_main);
```

with(by adding count)

```
    super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_main, count);
```

Comment: i changed to the super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.row_main, count);           but its not working yet.

Comment: check count by logging it, does it give positive value just before you call super.